# Real and Imaginary parts of solutions to a complex linear ODE system

Tags: differential-equations, complex

Consider a complex linear ODE system $x'=Ax$, where
$$A=\left(
\begin{matrix}
0&1\\
-2&-i
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
One can first find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using `JordanDecomposition` and get the general solutions with `MatrixExp`.

Here is my **question**:
Is there a quick way in *Mathematica* that I can get the solution in the form such that the real and imaginary parts are separated:
$$
v(t)=c_1v_1(t)+c_2iv_2(t)
$$ 
where $v_1(t),v_2(t)\in{\mathbb R}$?

Comment: Please post your code using `JordanDecomposition` and `MatrixExp` for completeness

Comment: Is there an issue with getting the solution and then using Re and Im to separate the real and imaginary parts? May be coupled with the use of ComplexExpand? A full MWE also helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linear system is easily solved generally by first calulating the MatrixExp. Then we can extract the real and imaginary parts.

Here we go

The complex matrix

```
A = {{0, 1}, {-2, -I}};
```

The matrix exp

```
At = MatrixExp[t A]

(* {{1/3 (2 Cos[t] + Cos[2 t] + I (2 Sin[t] - Sin[2 t])), 
  1/3 (I (-Cos[t] + Cos[2 t]) + Sin[t] + Sin[2 t])}, {1/
   3 (2 I (Cos[t] - Cos[2 t]) - 2 (Sin[t] + Sin[2 t])), 
  1/3 (Cos[t] + 2 Cos[2 t] + I (Sin[t] - 2 Sin[2 t]))}} *)
```

In matrix form:

```
At // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{3} (2 \text{Cos}[t]+\text{Cos}[2 t]+i (2 \text{Sin}[t]-\text{Sin}[2 t])) & \frac{1}{3} (i (-\text{Cos}[t]+\text{Cos}[2 t])+\text{Sin}[t]+\text{Sin}[2 t]) \\
 \frac{1}{3} (2 i (\text{Cos}[t]-\text{Cos}[2 t])-2 (\text{Sin}[t]+\text{Sin}[2 t])) & \frac{1}{3} (\text{Cos}[t]+2 \text{Cos}[2 t]+i (\text{Sin}[t]-2 \text{Sin}[2 t])) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The general solution vector is (where a == x[0] and b = y[0] are two constants)

```
{x, y} = At.{a, b}

(* {1/3 a (2 Cos[t] + Cos[2 t] + I (2 Sin[t] - Sin[2 t])) + 
  1/3 b (I (-Cos[t] + Cos[2 t]) + Sin[t] + Sin[2 t]), 
 1/3 b (Cos[t] + 2 Cos[2 t] + I (Sin[t] - 2 Sin[2 t])) + 
  1/3 a (2 I (Cos[t] - Cos[2 t]) - 2 (Sin[t] + Sin[2 t]))} *)
```

Direct proof that `{x,y}` solves the ODE

```
D[{x, y}, t] == A.{x, y} //Simplify

(* True *)
```

Ok.

Now we can calculate `Re` and `Im` of the matrix `At`

```
reAt = 1/2 ComplexExpand[At + Conjugate[At]];
reAt//MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{4 \text{Cos}[t]}{3}+\frac{2}{3} \text{Cos}[2 t]\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2 \text{Sin}[t]}{3}+\frac{2}{3} \text{Sin}[2 t]\right) \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{4 \text{Sin}[t]}{3}-\frac{4}{3} \text{Sin}[2 t]\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2 \text{Cos}[t]}{3}+\frac{4}{3} \text{Cos}[2 t]\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
imAt = 1/(2 I)  ComplexExpand[At - Conjugate[At]];
imAt//MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{4 \text{Sin}[t]}{3}-\frac{2}{3} \text{Sin}[2 t]\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{2 \text{Cos}[t]}{3}+\frac{2}{3} \text{Cos}[2 t]\right) \\
 \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{4 \text{Cos}[t]}{3}-\frac{4}{3} \text{Cos}[2 t]\right) & \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2 \text{Sin}[t]}{3}-\frac{4}{3} \text{Sin}[2 t]\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Check the decomposition

```
At == reAt + I imAt // Simplify

(*  True *)
```

Similarly you can decompose the solution vector {x,y}, which will result in slightly longer expressions in the case of complex initial values a and b.

Best regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: This is very helpful!